# Programatically registered scheduled bean does not schedule its work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following programatic registration of worker type `@Bean`s, but their work is not run every set time, when I create two of them in a class annotated with `@Configuration` it works.

Is there anything I'm missing?

```
@Component
public class WorkerRegistry {
    private final GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext;

    // other fields

    @PostConstruct
    public void initWorkers() {
        LOGGER.info("Initializing {} workers...", workerCount);
        for (int i = 1; i <= workerCount; i++) {
            genericApplicationContext.registerBean("thumbnailWorker" + i, ThumbnailWorker.class, jobManager, storeClient, resizer, pathBuilder, directory);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Finished worker initialization...");
    }
}
```

ThumbnailWorker class:

```
public class ThumbnailWorker {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${worker.delay}")
    @Transactional
    public void execute() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe what's happening here, Spring annotation parser is not parsing bean definition and that's leading to this issue.